# Number of arithmetic progressions that have common elements

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose we have a set of numbers $S=\{1,\dots, n\}$. The number of arithmetic progressions of length $k$ in $S$ is bounded by $n^2$, since every arithmetic progression is determined by its first two elements. Lets define $I_i$ and $I_j$ as some arithmetic progressions from this set. The question is to calculate the number of pairs of ($I_i, I_j$) that have:

1. one common element
2. two and more common elements

I even know the answers for (1) it is bounded by $n^3$ and for (2) by $n^2$. But I can't formally get these numbers.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\c}[2]{{}^{#1}{\mathbb C}_{#2}}$
No of APs are, here d is common difference:$$S(n,k)=(n-(k-1))_{d=1}+(n-2(k-1))_{d=2}+...\left(n-t(k-1)\right)$$
where $t\equiv t(n,k)$ is maximum possible common difference of the APs of length k i.e. $t\le n$.
So:
$$S(n,k)=nt-\frac{t(t-1)(k-1)}{2}\le nt\le n^2$$
Answer of $(1)$ would be $S(n,2k-1)$
 and to $(2)$ would be $S(n,k)-S(n,2k)-S(n,2k-1)$

An Explicit form of t would enable better proving bound for these two. Anyways:
$$t=\left\lfloor\frac{n-k}{k-1}\right\rfloor$$

Comment: Thanks! I agree with you regarding $S(n, k)$ formula, but it looks like the answer for (1) consider only pairs that:

1. share only last element for the first AP and first element for the second AP

2. have the same common difference

Comment: Perhaps I haven't formulated the task correctly, the original place was in this book: http://books.google.ru/books?id=RjnqVoB4VmUC&lpg=PA53&pg=PA54#v=onepage&q&f=false
Example 3.2